# empty array showing up for glob in php

Tags: php, opencart

This code is being used in opencart to find a list of themes..

```
$directories = glob(DIR_CATALOG . 'view/theme/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

In my config file I have `DIR_CATALOG` set to "c:xampp/htdocs/mysite/catalog/" and have 3 folders in the view/theme/ folder within catalog.

However when I `print_r($directories)` I get an empty array.

This is working fine on my server, when I migrated the site to local it wont pick up the themes inside the catalog folder.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locally my `DIR_CATALOG` string was missing a backslash after c:
This resolved the issue. Im not sure why though.